# Create Diagnostic setting with terraform to send specific log categories to Log Analytics and Storage Accounts?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am hoping to configure the streaming export of platform logs on Azure for some Kubernetes service, i wish to send some of the logs to log analytics workspace and others to a storage account. I wish to do this via terraform.

I looked at the documentation for [azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.60.0/docs/resources/monitor_diagnostic_setting), however i am unsure how to go about specifically allocating log categories between log analytics workspace and storage accounts.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule` resource? You have `storage_blob` block there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I Created a Diagnostic setting with Terraform to send specific log categories to Log Analytics and Storage Accounts and I was successful in provisioning the requirement.

To configure the streaming export of platform logs on Azure for a Kubernetes service and allocate log categories between a Log Analytics workspace and a storage account using Terraform, you can use the azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting resource.

**My Terraform configuration:**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "main"{
    name = "v-bolliv"
}
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  name                = "demovk"
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  dns_prefix          = "demovkaks1"
 
   default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "og-analyticsvk-workspace"
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  # Add other required configuration for your Log Analytics workspace
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "demostoragevksb"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location                 = "eastus"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"
  # Add other required configuration for your storage account
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "example" {
  name                = "diagnosticvk-setting"
  target_resource_id  = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.id
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  
  enabled_log {
    category = "kube-apiserver"
  }

  enabled_log {
    category = "kube-controller-manager"
  }

}

resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "example" {
  name                = "monitorlog"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
  capacity            = 2
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_log_profile" "example" {
  name                = "default"
 
   categories = [
    "Action",
    "Delete",
    "Write",
  ]

  locations = [
    "eastus",
    "global",
  ]

  servicebus_rule_id = "${azurerm_eventhub_namespace.example.id}/authorizationrules/RootManageSharedAccessKey"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id

  retention_policy {
    enabled = true
    days    = 7
  }
}
```

Specify the desired log categories and their corresponding destinations within the azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting resource. In the above, kube-apiserver and kube-controller-manager logs are sent to the Log Analytics workspace, while other logs will be sent to the storage account.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]